# Jtable swing get rows data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i have a little problems with getting rows data from a jTable :

```
for (int i = 0; i < TB_Accounts.getRowCount(); i++) {
    username = TB_Accounts.getModel().getValueAt(i, i);
    password = TB_Accounts.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1);

    if (username == null || password == null) {
        continue;
    }

    System.out.println("userName : " + username);
    System.out.println("password : " + password);

    if (!username.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !password.toString().equalsIgnoreCase((""))) {
        accouts.add(new Account(username.toString(), password.toString()));

        System.out.println("in :: userName : " + username);
        System.out.println("in :: password : " + password);
    }    
}
```

the problem is that a always get all data from the table except the last row, i dont know wht .

Comment: should it be:  username = TB_Accounts.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0); ?

Comment: yea, i found it, thanks :: ps : how to set the thread solved??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the loop on first glance but looks like line two could be the culprit:

```
...
username = TB_Accounts.getModel().getValueAt(i, i);
...
```

That is probably returning null as you proceed through the rows and subsequently causing the loop to skip via the `continue` call which occurs if username or password are null. Change to:

```
...
username = TB_Accounts.getModel().getValueAt(i,0);
...
```